# Telerik MVC Grid Filter is Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

The Telerik MVC grid I am using is shown below. The data is displaying in the grid but the
filterable attribute is not working, though the "Filter Icon" is displaying. I have registered the scripts and css in the layout.cshtml but I dont know why the **filterable action is not working** and **sometimes the Column Widths are ignored and the grid is rendering in a default size**.

```
@model IEnumerable<Customers>

@(Html.Telerik()
    .Grid(Model) 
    .Name("Customers") 
    .PrefixUrlParameters(false) 
    .Columns(columns=>
                { 
                 columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerId).Title("CustomerId").Width(50);<br/>
                 columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerStatus).Title("Customer Status").Width(70);
                 columns.Bound(c=>c.CityId).Title("CityID").Width(50);  
                 }
    .Filterable() 
    .Sortable(sort=>sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
)
```

layout.cshtml (registered scripts and stylesheets):

```
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.vista.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)))

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify the size of the grid, you could wrap it in a div:

```
<div style="width:300px;">
   @(Html.Telerik()...
</div>
```

Also, make sure you enable sorting/filtering in your grid:

```
.Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
```

If it still doesn't work, ensure that the script file being created by the Telerik script manager can be served by your web server (view source, grab the .axd link and paste it into your address bar).

One more thing:

> Don't forget that the columns will expand to accomodate all their
>   content so be sure your column widths match your parent div.

You could also use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to examine any script issues in your page.

Comment: I used like you said                                      .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))                              even this not working.                                                       Filter action is not at all working. Stuck on this issue since 2 days.No correct answer for this even in TELERIK FORUM.

Comment: Did you use Firebug to examine what is happening when the page loads? If so, what was the output?

Comment: I am getting the same result in FireFox too. Actually, what you want me to check with firebug.Allscripts are loaded as expected.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose this without some more information. Are you able to put a partial project together or even temporarily publish something online? I constructed a sample grid using the latest Telerik MVC controls and it worked perfectly for me, including column widths and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Datakeys or if you have enabled custom binding on the grid action method, removing that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a very interesting thing. The filtering on my grid was not working. The icon was there, but it was not clickable. And it all was acting weird. For example at sorting it was adding a long tail to the query string. And I spent two days on this. Until I found the problem. I had four tabs on a page, and in each I was loading a partial. Each partial was containing one grid. The first three grids (on the first three tabs) were working fine. The fourth was not. I have moved the last partial in the first tab, it was working fine, but the grid in the third tab was not working anymore. The problem was that only three grids on a page were working. If I had all the four grids on the first tab, only the first three were working, the fourth was not. Very weird. Didn't find the source of the problem though...

Answer (score 0):

Telerik grids really are terrible. If a dataype is datatimeoffset for a column the filter will never work.